# Difficulties trying to build & run HipHop PHP Compiler on Ubuntu 9.10... any ideas?

Tags: php, build

It seems to not get past this step:

```
[ 16%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/hphp_runtime_static.dir/lib/system/gen/sys/dynamic_table_func.no.cpp.o
```

**UPDATE**
The above was just slow. I left my desk and came back after several hours, and the build had completed successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a similar [post on the mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/hiphop-php-dev/browse_thread/thread/2224a8e9620691b0/222c0085d9ba2ec7?#222c0085d9ba2ec7) but unfortunately it seems the user that hit this problem somehow got past it and got to an actual error message later on in the thread.  You might be able to pick up on the thread or contact that person and see if they can detail how they got past this step though.

Comment: That step just seems to be crazy slow - I checked and notice the dynamic_table_func.no.cpp source file is 1,874,244 bytes (1.8M) of pure C++! Eventually g++ chews through it. I think it took at least 2 hours.